# Is there any way to access a google sheets, and read it column by column, without the google API (in python)

Tags: python

I want to, for example, check column 3 of row 7, and see what is written there. I can't use the google sheets API

Answer (score 0):

only if it has been [published](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870) to the web, or by "downloading" the web view. There are some other methods, but these are "initiated" from the sheet itself, not from separate code not running on the sheet.